# Infinispan 6.0 CDI and default configuration

Tags: glassfish, cdi, infinispan

I'm having problems defining configuration for a CDI application (glassfish 4).

I have:

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "example")
public String getSomething(String something){
    logger.debug("getSomething "+something);
    return "this is "+something;
}
```

This works as expected, the second time is called is not executed because it's cached

However, I want to specify a configuration for my caches. I have tried writing a infinispan.xml file (in src/main/resources), but it's ignored. I have also tried with both:

```
    @Produces
@Default
public Configuration defaultEmbeddedCacheConfiguration() {
    return new ConfigurationBuilder().expiration().lifespan(3000l)
            .eviction()
            .strategy(EvictionStrategy.LRU)
            .maxEntries(2)
            .build();
}

@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public EmbeddedCacheManager defaultEmbeddedCacheManager() {
    return new DefaultCacheManager(defaultEmbeddedCacheConfiguration());
}
```

But these methods are never called.

I have also tried with @ConfigureCache

My dependencies are:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: Are you sure that you CDI is working?Is `beans.xml` correctly in `META-INF` or `WEB-INF` folder?

Comment: Yes, sure. Beans.xml contains infinispan interceptors and I can see the traces from infinispan

Comment: Finally it worked, I just had to inject the EmbeddedCacheManager into some bean (I'm using a webListener for this now). The problem was that this EmbeddedCacheManager was not being used at the creation and the default one was created.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense...I am glad you made that work